# I have a problem hosting a project made in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, vercel

I have Next.js project. When I connect MUI I have problems with verions

[image]

My project works in localhost but it is not working in hosting. I tried this one --legacy-peer-deps but it is still not working

Comment: can you please share your package.json code with us? Share necessary details always for better approach.

Comment: Always share the code/error/log as a code-block instead of image. Maybe this will help you to understand it better: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11070125

Comment: Looks like it's looking for react 17 but on server its react 18. Make sure you are running react 17 on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer! I installed mui and material-ui. When I deleted material-ui and installed mui/lab it worked